# Is there any method/way in javascript to add a child node to list element dynamically?

Tags: javascript, list, dynamic

If I have an unordered list like

```
<ul id="list">
<li>Helo World-1</li>
<li>Helo World-2</li>
<li>Helo World-3</li>
</ul>
```

I want to add a sublist item to it dynamically. Is there any method in javascript to do that. How could I do it. 
**edit**
I need an item at next level, i.e. a sub list of Helo World that I mentioned in OP too, something like as under. One more issue here is that I need the items to be a permanent part of my code.

```
 <ul id="list">
    <li>Helo World-1</li>
    <li>Helo World-2</li>
    <li>Helo World-3</li>
       <ul>
         <li>One</li>
         <li>Two</li>
      </ul>
 </ul>
```

Comment: How do you know to which `<li>` you have to add the sub items?

Comment: Have not thought that before.I think to 1st add these at the end, & once done. I Could then try to implement method Tim Down mentioned i.e. ul.insertBefore(li, document.getElementById("list_item_id"));

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Using pure DOM methods:

```
var ul = document.getElementById("list");
var li = document.createElement("li");
li.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Your list item text"));
```

To add the list item to the end of the list:

```
ul.appendChild(li);
```

To insert the list item between existing list items (note you'd have to give the existing list item an id in this example):

```
ul.insertBefore(li, document.getElementById("list_item_id"));
```

### Update

If you want to add a nested list, you'll need to add it to a list item rather than directly inside the list in order for it to be valid:

```
var lis = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");

var lastLi = lis[lis.length - 1];

var nestedUl = document.createElement("ul");
var nestedLi = nestedUl.appendChild(document.createElement("li"));
nestedLi.appendChild(document.createTextNode("One"));

lastLi.appendChild(nestedUl);
```

Comment: Nice `insertBefore` inclusion. +1

Comment: thanX Tim but same thing is here. Its adding item on 1st level, I need sub level item added.

Comment: thanX a Lot Tim. Can you kindly put all code together that is needed to add nested list item. Bec I am not sure how should I merge this code with one you put earlier as you used tagName property of element that is crated in code snippet.

Comment: @YuriKolovsky: Not in this situation: creating an element and all its children before adding it to the DOM is as good as you can do. A `DocumentFragment` would only help if you were inserting several sibling elements at the same point in the DOM.

Comment: This does not work. last call lastLi.appendChild(nestedUl) will fail. [jsfddler](http://jsfiddle.net/DFHWd/221/)

Comment: @ChrisJi: No, it works fine. The problem in your jsFiddle is that you missed out the the line that declares the `ul` variable. See http://jsfiddle.net/DFHWd/222/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('<li>...</li>').appendTo($('#list')); /* in jquery */
```

otherwise straight js

```
var mylist = document.getElementById('list');
mylist.appendChild(document.createElement('li'));
```

Note: if you need to set also text

```
var mylist = document.getElementById('list');
var newli  = document.createElement('li');

newli.innerHTML('Helo World ' + mylist.getElementsByTagName('li').length + 1);
mylist.appendChild(newli);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've created a sample in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/HujcL/)

```
var el = document.getElementById("list");

var li = document.createElement("li");
li.innerHTML = "item";

el.appendChild(li);
```

You can go through the [w3schools html dom reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp) to see how we can manipulate the html elements using javascript.

But I think the cleaner way will be to use a third party library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) which will allow a much easier way to manipulate the dom.

ex: If use jQuery this will be as easy as

```
$("<li>...</li>").appendTo("#list")
```

EDIT:
Based on your edit you can try this,

```
var ul = document.getElementById("list");
ul.children[2].innerHTML = "<ul><li>sub 1</li><li>sub 2</li><li>sub 3</li></ul>";
```

This will get the 3rd `<li>` of the `<ul>` and add a sublist to it

Comment: thanX Arun, what I need is a sublevel list to Helo world. I added detail to my question.

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK, there is no equivalent HTML DOM object for list.
Anyway you can use the innerHTML:

```
var list = document.getElementById("list");
var item = "<li>New Item</li>";
list.innerHTML += item;
```

Comment: This is a very *bad* way to do it, `.innerHTML` will erase all event handlers and cause other issues.