# adding user input to a list of text items on a html page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a textbox for user input with a submit button. I would like for the user to be able to put in some input, and have the input appear in a list underneath the input box, maybe into a table using some kind of javascript function. To me this seems like a fairly simple concept but I can't find any tutorials that will show me how to do it, can anyone recommend any or tell me what the best, most attractive looking approach to this would be?

EDIT- Here's what I've tried:

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>



<script type="text/javascript">

document.getElementById("add").onClick = function() {

    var text = document.getElementById("idea").value;

    var li = "<li>" + text + </li>;

    document.getElementById("list").appendChild(li);
}

</script>

<input type='text' id = 'idea' />
<input type='button' value = 'add to list' id = 'add'>

<ul id= 'list'> 


  <li> <b>Topics</b></li> 

    </ul>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Show use what you've tried

Comment: Also here's some related thread: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214948/is-there-any-method-way-in-javascript-to-add-a-child-node-to-list-element-dynami](Is there any method/way in javascript to add a child node to list element dynamically?), [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17183713/add-li-element-in-ul-using-jquery](add li element in ul using jquery)

Comment: You need to create node text. with createTextNode and create an element as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can give a quick run through of what you'll need. First, you'll want your basic text input with an ID:

```
<input type='text' id='idea' />
```

And obviously a button to add to the list:

```
<input type='button' value='add to list' id='add' />
```

And a list to be adding to:

```
<ul id='list'></ul>
```

Now for the fun JS, see the play-by-play in the comments

```
//Defining a listener for our button, specifically, an onclick handler
document.getElementById("add").onclick = function() {
    //First things first, we need our text:
    var text = document.getElementById("idea").value; //.value gets input values

    //Now construct a quick list element
    var li = "<li>" + text + "</li>";

    //Now use appendChild and add it to the list!
    document.getElementById("list").appendChild(li);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @tymeJV, that looks as though it'll do exactly what I need. Forgive the extreme newbie question, but how exactly do I use the javascript? Do I encase it in <script tags within the html?

Comment: Yep, you're going to want to do some intro JavaScript tutorials, this will explain how to implement this.

Comment: Ok so I've been looking at tutorials and making attempts, but I cant seem to get it working- will you have a look at the edit above and see if you can point me in the right direction?

Comment: Dont capitalize the "C" in `onClick`, it should be `onclick` -- Also, put your `script` after your HTML. So you'll have `<body>content...<script></script></body>`

Comment: It still doesn't work, any other ideas as to what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: @bookthief you need to create a element node and a text node. Here it is `document.getElementById("add").onclick  = function() {

    var node = document.createElement("Li");
    var text = document.getElementById("user_input").value; 
 var textnode=document.createTextNode(text);
    node.appendChild(textnode);
    document.getElementById("list_item").appendChild(node);
}
` it should work

Answer (score 3):

Below is the basic JavaScript code that will do the job.

```
document.getElementById("add").onclick  = function() {

    var node = document.createElement("Li");
    var text = document.getElementById("user_input").value; 
    var textnode=document.createTextNode(text);
    node.appendChild(textnode);
    document.getElementById("list_item").appendChild(node);
}
```

HTML

```
<input type="button" id="add" value="Add New">
<ol id="list_item">

</ol>
```

Comment: Upvoted because unlike the accepted answer, this *does* work, except that you need to add `<input type='text' id='user_input' />` so the user can input text. Drop the Javascript inside `<script></script>` tags, and you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

here is a  basic jquery implementation:

```
(function($){
    $('#myform').submit(function(e){
        var val = $('#in').val();
        $('ul.list').append('<li>' + val + '</li>');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MW8HS/

Comment: No need to use a `.find` on an element with an ID.

Comment: Is Jquery implemented the same way as javascript- ie between two script tags?

Comment: you need to include the jQuery library - easiest from a CDN like so `<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>` in the head of your html, then you can access the jQuery $ object within your normal javascript. e.g include the library and then put the above code within script tags in the body of the page and it should work - check the fiddle for html markup

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type='text' id='idea'>
<input type="button" id="add" value="Add New">
<script>document.getElementById("add").onclick  = function() {

    var node = document.createElement("Li");
    var text = document.getElementById("idea").value; 
    var textnode=document.createTextNode(text);
    node.appendChild(textnode);
    document.getElementById("list").appendChild(node);
}
</script>
<ul id='list'></ul>
```

Comment: just u need to call list after script

Comment: When giving an answer, you should at least explain why your code is solving OP's issue. This will help him understand and others that might have the same question too.

Answer (score -1):

I think it work but not changing li style:

```
document.getElementById('add').onclick = function(){
  var text = document.getElementById('idea').value;     
  var node = document.createElement("li");    
  var textNode = document.createTextNode(text);    
  node.appendChild(textNode);     
  document.getElementById('list').appendChild(node);
};
```